# How do I setup a really simple WCF Data service and entity model that works?

Tags: wpf, wcf, entity-framework, data-binding

Ok this is going to seem really daft but but essentially this is what i'm trying to do in a nutshell ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465161.aspx

The problem is that when I create the WCF Data Service and browse to it everything looks good at the root level and as soon as I leave the root I get http 500 errors.

I get no decent information on how to fix the error or what went wrong it says "Internal server error" ... not helpful.

So my question is sort of twofold ... 
How do I setup a simple WCF Data service that relies on an entity model then bind some simple data to a listbox or something in a WPF client?

but also ...

How do I debug those http 500 errors?

Just for clarification:

I followed the steps here ...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728275.aspx
... to create the model and service.

The root url "http://localhost/Northwind.svc" works fine.

Browsing to "http://localhost/Northwind.svc/Orders" causes a http 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helps a LOT:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308172942/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx)

Also download [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) you can use it to monitor requests/responses (See [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/lorenh/tip-for-using-fiddler-on-localhost))

Answer (score 1):

I would start by attaching the debugger to your service when you use your browser to access it.

You might want to try a different client because there usually is a response from a service besides the 500 errorcode, but a browser only shows a 500 error page.

Comment: I have tried this ... the debugger does not seem to kick in. There's pretty much no code in the service itself (my class anyway) there's only the initialisation method and that works fine. The debugger never gets hit ... it's like something behind the whole framework is dying.  Of course the iis logs don't reveal anything either.